# Apache-Commons: Getting a CopyStreamException: IOException when I use CopyStreamEvent

Tags: java, inputstream, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I am trying to upload a file to an FTP server using the *apache-commons*' *FTPClient* class. *storeFile*() works with no error, but instead of using it, I wanted to create a listener so I could keep an eye on the upload progress.

When I run the code it happily connects and calls *uploadFile*() - Which in turn throws the *CopyStreamException: IOException*.

I'm not good at deciding what causes the exception to be thrown, could it be my "listener" object?

This is how I do it:

```
/** Upload a file to the server */
public boolean uploadFile (String localFile, String serverFile, CopyStreamAdapter listener ) throws IOException, FTPConnectionClosedException
{
    /*
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(localFile);
    boolean result = storeFile(serverFile, in);
    in.close();
    return result;
    */

    InputStream stO = new BufferedInputStream( this.retrieveFileStream(serverFile), this.getBufferSize());
    OutputStream stD = new FileOutputStream(localFile);

    org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(stO, stD, this.getBufferSize(), org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamEvent.UNKNOWN_STREAM_SIZE, listener );
    this.completePendingCommand();

    // if we get this far, it's rainbows all the way down!
    return true ;
}
```

listener:

```
CopyStreamAdapter listener = new org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamAdapter()
{
    public void bytesTransferred (long totalBytesTransferred, int bytesTransferred, long streamSize)
    {
        // show progress
        System.out.println( "Upload progress: " + bytesTransferred + " of " + totalBytesTransferred ) ;
    }
} ;

f = new ftpClientWrapper() ;   // my class instance.
f.uploadFile(filename, "/public/dropfolder/test/testfile.test" , listener ) ;  // i've validated filename and uploadpath
```

edit: This is the stack trace:

```
Error on FTP upload: org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying.
org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying.
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(Util.java:129)
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(Util.java:173)
    at dk.capsize.ftpapp.ftpClientWrapper.uploadFile(JakartaFtpWrapper.java:105)
    at FTPApp.main(FTPApp.java:63)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the IOException?

Comment: Oops - I forgot about that :)